# Setting a registry value Programatically using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, registry

I would like to change the IE setting under:

> Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted Zones -> Custom Level -> Miscellaneous -> Enable

I have done this with other registry keys like "Disable Debugging" and such.

But I can't seem to set this value to enable.
Here is what I have so far:

```
WshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\SO\MISC\CrossDomainData\Default",1, "REG_DWORD"
```

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Do you have permissions to modify this registry entry? You may need administrator privs (i.e., elevation) in order to do it.